# Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary

Tags: symbols, glossaries

I am trying to use the approach given in the solution here [Glossary entry with extra parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228996/glossary-entry-with-extra-parameter) (which looks really neat) for an application where i am having more than one glossary; in the original i have only a symbolslist and abbreviations, but here's an mwe adapting the symbolslist to the main list provided in the solution of the link above

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
%this line is new
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\glsarg}{i}

\newglossaryentry{BetragVektor}{
     name=\ensuremath{|\overline{u_i}|},
     text=|\overline{u_{\glsarg}}|,
    description={ABC}}
\newglossaryentry{s:tP}{
    name=\ensuremath{T_p\mathcal M},
    text=T_\glsarg\mathcal M,
    description={},
    type=symbolslist %in own list
}
% modify the entry's format

\defglsentryfmt{%
  \let\orgglsarg\glsarg
  \ifdefempty\glsinsert
  {}%
  {%
    \let\glsarg\glsinsert
    \let\glsinsert\relax
  }%
  \glsgenentryfmt
  \let\glsarg\orgglsarg
}

\begin{document}

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[2]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[]$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}[2]$

$\gls{s:tP}[]$

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

As mentioned, the only thing new is that I introduce a second list. The solution still seems to work for the main list as the result shows.

[image: symbols]

So somehow the new argument gets added in the and and `\glsarg` stays the same. How can I solve this, such that my new glossary also can have optional parameters on their entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Method 1: Specific Glossary

`\defglsentryfmt` has an optional argument that indicates which glossary this format should govern. If omitted, `main` is assumed, so you also need to do the same for the new glossary:

```
\defglsentryfmt[symbolslist]{%
  \let\orgglsarg\glsarg
  \ifdefempty\glsinsert
  {}%
  {%
    \let\glsarg\glsinsert
    \let\glsinsert\relax
  }%
  \glsgenentryfmt
  \let\glsarg\orgglsarg
}
```

### Method 2: All Glossaries

Alternatively, you can just redefine `\glsentryfmt` to apply to all glossaries. (Individual glossaries may be overridden using `\defglsentryfmt`, which `\newacronym` does automatically.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
%this line is new
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\glsarg}{i}

\newglossaryentry{BetragVektor}{
     name=\ensuremath{|\overline{u_i}|},
     text=|\overline{u_{\glsarg}}|,
    description={ABC}}
\newglossaryentry{s:tP}{
    name=\ensuremath{T_p\mathcal M},
    text=T_\glsarg\mathcal M,
    description={},
    type=symbolslist %in own list
}
% modify the entry's format

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \let\orgglsarg\glsarg
  \ifdefempty\glsinsert
  {}%
  {%
    \let\glsarg\glsinsert
    \let\glsinsert\relax
  }%
  \glsgenentryfmt
  \let\glsarg\orgglsarg
}

\begin{document}

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[2]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[]$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}[2]$

$\gls{s:tP}[]$

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of result]

### Method 3: Specific Category (`glossaries-extra`)

If you want to use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), this is a better method:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\glsdefaultarg}{i}
\newcommand*{\glsarg}{\glsdefaultarg}

\newglossaryentry{BetragVektor}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
     name=\ensuremath{|\overline{u_i}|},
     text=|\overline{u_{\glsarg}}|,
    description={ABC}}
\newglossaryentry{s:tP}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
    name=\ensuremath{T_p\mathcal M},
    text=T_\glsarg\mathcal M,
    description={},
    type=symbolslist %in own list
}
% modify the entry's format

\preto\glsentryfmt{%
  \glsifcategory{\glslabel}{arg}% if category set to "arg"
  {%
    \ifdefempty\glsinsert
    {\let\glsarg\glsdefaultarg}%
    {%
      \let\glsarg\glsinsert
      \let\glsinsert\empty
    }%
  }%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[2]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[]$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}[2]$

$\gls{s:tP}[]$

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Now you just need to tag which entries require an argument by using `category=arg` in the entry definition. You can also store the default argument, if it should be different for each entry. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\glsarg}{}

\newglossaryentry{BetragVektor}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
    user1={i},
     name=\ensuremath{|\overline{u_i}|},
     text=|\overline{u_{\glsarg}}|,
    description={ABC}}
\newglossaryentry{s:tP}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
    user1={p},
    name=\ensuremath{T_p\mathcal M},
    text=T_\glsarg\mathcal M,
    description={},
    type=symbolslist %in own list
}
% modify the entry's format

\preto\glsentryfmt{%
  \glsifcategory{\glslabel}{arg}% if category set to "arg"
  {%
    \ifdefempty\glsinsert
    {\glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{useri}{\glsarg}}%
    {%
      \let\glsarg\glsinsert
      \let\glsinsert\empty
    }%
  }%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[1]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[2]$

$\gls{BetragVektor}[]$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}$

$\gls{s:tP}[1]$

$\gls{s:tP}[2]$

$\gls{s:tP}[]$

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

### Method 4: Specific Entry (`glossaries-extra`)

Here's another method: use `\glsxtrfmt` for the cases where a parameter is required. This deviates from the concept of an optional parameter, but it's worth considering as it doesn't alter the normal display format.

A designated field (by default `user1`, but may be changed by redefining `\GlsXtrFmtField`) stores the name (without the leading backslash) of a command that takes a **single mandatory** argument that's associated with the formatting of the given entry. Then `\glsxtrfmt[`*options*`]{`*label*`}{`*parameter*`}` applies that command to *parameter* (encapsulated by `\glslink` to index and, if enabled, hyperlink to the glossary).

For example, define:

```
\newcommand{\vectorlength}[1]{|\overline{u_{#1}}|}
\newcommand{\tP}[1]{T_#1\mathcal{M}}
```

Then the entries can be defined as:

```
\newglossaryentry{BetragVektor}{
 user1={vectorlength},
 name=\ensuremath{\vectorlength{i}},
 description={ABC}}

\newglossaryentry{s:tP}{
 user1={tP},
 name=\ensuremath{\tP{p}},
 description={},
 type=symbolslist
}
```

So now `\gls{BetragVektor}` uses the value of the `first`/`text` field (as normal, which here is obtained from the `name` field) but `\glsxtrfmt{BetragVektor}{1}` is essentially like `\glslink{BetragVektor}{\vectorlength{1}}`.¹

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}

\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand{\BetragVektor}[1]{|\overline{u_{#1}}|}
\newcommand{\tP}[1]{T_#1\mathcal{M}}

\newglossaryentry{BetragVektor}{
 user1={BetragVektor},
 name=\ensuremath{\BetragVektor{i}},
 description={ABC}}

\newglossaryentry{s:tP}{
 user1={tP},
 name=\ensuremath{\tP{p}},
 description={},
 type=symbolslist %in own list
}

\begin{document}

$\glsxtrfmt{BetragVektor}{1}$

$\gls{BetragVektor}$

$\glsxtrfmt{BetragVektor}{1}$

$\glsxtrfmt{BetragVektor}{2}$

$\gls{BetragVektor}$

$\glsxtrfmt{s:tP}{1}$

$\gls{s:tP}$

$\glsxtrfmt{s:tP}{1}$

$\glsxtrfmt{s:tP}{2}$

$\gls{s:tP}$

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

There are some more examples in Section 3.1 "Functions" of [`glossaries-extra` and `bib2gls`: An Introductory Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls-begin.pdf) (that section is general to `glossaries-extra` regardless of whether or not you're using `bib2gls`).

---

¹ It's a little more complicated: `\glsxtrfmt[`*options*`]{`*label*`}{`*text*`}` effectively does `\glslink[`*default options*`,`*options*`]{`*label*`}{\glsxtrfmtdisplay{`*csname*`}{`*text*`}{}}` where *csname* is the control sequence name obtained from the designated field. (If the field is unset *csname* defaults to `@firstofone`.)

The starred version `\glsxtrfmt*[`*options*`]{`*label*`}{`*text*`}[`*insert*`]` is effectively `\glslink[`*default options*`,`*options*`]{`*label*`}{\glsxtrfmtdisplay{`*csname*`}{`*text*`}{`*insert*`}}`.

Comment: Oh, that was an easy fix - actually it's enough to have it for just my `symbolslist`, so having the one list entry fixed already solves the problem. Thanks for the fast (and so simple) answer :)

Comment: @Ronny I added `glossaries-extra` alternative for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a safer version, because only some (all of one category) are extended by an optional argument and not all symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen the third option as mentioned in Nicola's answer and it works like charm!

However there are a few remarks I would like to make regarding the syntax which weren't apparent to me and I had to experiment a little to make it work as expected. So:

1. You can build other glossary entries on top of more primitive ones simply by calling `\gls{<primitive entry name>}` inside the respective field (see example; i guess that works for the whole glossaries package).
2. You can pass the argument from the more complicated glossary entry to the more primitive one (`category=arg` has to be set in the complicated entry as well for you to be able to pass the argument).

   - the argument is passed implicitly (see example)
3. And a few other things mentioned in the comments of the example

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newcommand*{\glsarg}{}

\newglossaryentry{simple}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
    user1={a},% default argument for \glsarg
    name={\(A_{i}\)},
    text={A_{\glsarg}},
    description={simpler}}
\newglossaryentry{simple2}{
    category=arg,% requires an argument
    user1={b},
    name={\(B_{\glsarg}\)},% \glsarg has no effect here nor does user1=b, it has to be B_{b} to appear that way in the glossary, this will evaluate to just \(B\)
    text={B_{\glsarg}},% \glsarg works as usual here
    description={simpler}}
\newglossaryentry{complex}{
    category=arg,% required to require an argument
    name={\(C_{\gls{simple}[k]}\)},% will evaluate as \(C_{A_k}\) in the glossary
    text={C_{\gls{simple}}},% \glsarg will be passed to \gls{simple} without mentioning it here
    description={more complex. You can use \(\gls{simple2}\) here as well}}

\preto\glsentryfmt{%
    \glsifcategory{\glslabel}{arg}%
    {%
        \ifdefempty\glsinsert
        {\glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{useri}{\glsarg}}%
        {%
            \let\glsarg\glsinsert
            \let\glsinsert\empty
        }%
    }%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}

\[\gls{simple}\]% shows as A_a
\[\gls{simple}[i]\]% shows as A_i
\[\gls{simple2}[j]\]% shows as B_j
\[\gls{complex}[k]\]% shows as C_{A_k}

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't nest `\gls` inside of descriptions of other entries.

Comment: As a supplement to @ChristianHupfer's comment, see the section [Nested Links](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested) in the `glossaries-extra` documentation.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot Oh, I have already rewritten my glossary and document to use the nesting :-D how bad can it get? So it only works because it takes `\gls` inside the definitions as `\glstext[hyper=false,noindex]`?

Comment: @VaNa As long as you group it and have `hyper=false` (e.g. `{\gls*{simple}[k]}`) and don't use it for abbreviations (or something that has different `first` and `text` values) and you don't need the corresponding `\glsentry...` to be expandable (which it won't be anyway, since the values are in math-mode) and it doesn't interfere with the case-changing commands like `\Gls` (which aren't applicable in this case) then you should be okay. Suppressing the indexing isn't quite such a problem (unless you feel it inappropriate). The other issues are the primary concerns.

Comment: It might be easier to have a wrapper command, for example `\newcommand{\ngls}[2]{{\gls[hyper=false]{#1}[#2]}}` and use that (e.g. `name={\(C_{\ngls{simple}{k}}\)}, text={C_{\ngls{simple}{}}}`).

Comment: @Nicola Talbot Thank you very much, that is a good solution for me because I already have `\let\g\gls` there since I use `\gls` extensively. Just one more question. Can I somehow overcome an issue with `\gls{simple}^a` not having the  upper index above the lower one but treating the `A_a` as a box becoming roughly `A_a^{\: a}`?

Comment: @VaNa Use the optional argument `\gls{simple}[^a]`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot You got me, that works but I have given this example to keep it simple however I actually need that for the `complex` case which does not work this way. I am sorry to bother you all the time btw :D

Comment: @VaNa If you can create a MWE demonstrating it you can always post a question with a reference to this one.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Didn't know you weren't meant to nest. I've been nesting for ages. However, I don't use `glossaries` with `hyperref`, which probably helps. OP: `\let\g\gls` is horrible. You really ought never do this. That is, unless you first check that `\g` is not already defined.

Comment: @cfr Why is it so bad? Does something like `\let\g\undefined` in front of it help?

Comment: Do you know if `\g` is already used? If not, you don't know what you're overwriting. `\newcommand\g{}\let\g\gls` is better as you'll get an error if it is already defined. But you are also making your code less readable in order to save typing 2 characters. `\gls` is hardly a macro with a long name. It would be better to set up a shortcut in your editor if you really want to save the typing. But at least set it so that either you check if it is defined or you use something which will do the check for you.

Comment: @cfr It's not just the problem with hyperlinks. It's documented in the `glossaries` manual (for example, in the 3rd red box near the start of [6. Links to Glossary Entries](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glslink)) and [explained in more detail in the `glossaries-extra` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I didn't realise that red box applied to using them inside entries since it only mentioned captions and titles etc. I realise 'moving argument' is more general, but I guess I'd have expected a specific note if it applied to use inside the fields of glossary entries, since cross-referencing other entries is a pretty common thing to do in the `description` of a term in a glossary, and this isn't a field affected by the warning on 126 either. Is there a good alternative?

Comment: @cfr It's not a problem in the `description` field (and is quite common, as you mention) as long as you don't use `\glsdesc`. The first red box relates to section headings. The 3rd red box is "Avoid nesting these commands. For example don’t do `\glslink{⟨label⟩}{\gls {⟨label2⟩}}` as this is likely to cause problems. By implication, this means that you should avoid using any of these commands within the text, first, short or long keys (or their plural equivalent) or any other key that you plan to access through these commands. (For example, the symbol key if you intend to use `\glssymbol`.) "

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Oh, right. OK. I thought from the discussion that all nesting was to be avoided, where that includes any use in an entry at all. I don't remember whether I ever use them anywhere else, but it was `description` I had in mind. I don't use `\glsdesc` that I recall either. I just want cross-references in descriptions, really.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot So Christian's initial comment in this discussion is incorrect? There isn't a general problem with nesting them in descriptions of other entries?

Comment: @cfr Just to confirm: it's okay to have `\gls` in the `description` field if you don't use `\glsdesc` and if you don't try using `\glsentrydesc` in the final optional argument of arguments like `\gls` (or insert the description in any other way into text produced by commands like `\gls`, for example in `\glsentryfmt`). When I read Christian's initial comment, I interpreted "descriptions" as meaning field values in general (such as the `text` field, which will cause a problem) rather than specifically the value of the `description` field. My concern was focused on `text={C_{\gls{simple}}}`.