# Add or continue subscript

Tags: glossaries, subscripts

Assuming I have defined a glossary entry named `v_rob` as `v_{\text{robot}}` and in my text I want to describe the robot velocity at time `t` using a subscript, I was tempted to write `\gls{v_rob}_t`. This, however, produces an error as it is a double subscript. I was hoping to get the equivalent of `v_{\text{robot},t}`. As I frequently refer to such variables at different timepoints (e.g. `t`, `t-1`, `t+1`, ...), in the present form I can't really use the glossary entry and have to instead manually type `v_{\text{robot},t}`, `v_{\text{robot},t-1}` in my text.

My current workaround is adding a negative space between the glossary entry and the new subscript, but it's obviously not the best way to do it: `\gls{v_rob}\hspace{-0.7pt}_t`

Is there an elegant way to use subscripts with my glossary entry?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just a personal habit to avoid such subscripts: I write something like this as functions (like `v_{\text{robot}}(t)`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in what I'm doing it's everybody is using the subscript notation.

Comment: How about defining vrob as `{v_{\text{robot}}}`; i.e., in a group?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this lowers the second subscript. Basically I want to get a_{bc} and you propose {a_b}_c.

Comment: You can use `\glsadd{v_rob}v_{\mathrm{robot},t}`, possibly with some `hyperref` trickery for getting a link.

Comment: You need to use the optional argument `\gls{v_rob}[_t]`.

Comment: Actually it seems more like a duplicate of [Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316777)