# How to fix superscripts in glossaries with parameters

Tags: glossaries, superscripts, glossaries-extra

Inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316777/symbols-with-optional-parameter-in-glossaries-with-newglossary/401108?noredirect=1#comment999872_401108) I created a glossary entry with an optional parameter as a subscript. However when I try to have a superscript there as well I can't use the trick where I pass the superscript as an optional argument because I already have one. Is there any workaround?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\glsnoexpandfields

\newglossaryentry{A}{
    category={arg},
    user1={1},
    name={\(A_{\glsarg}\)},
    text={A_{\glsarg}},
    description={A}}

\preto\glsentryfmt{%
    \glsifcategory{\glslabel}{arg}% if category set to "arg"
    {%
        \ifdefempty\glsinsert
        {\glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{useri}{\glsarg}}%
        {%
            \let\glsarg\glsinsert
            \let\glsinsert\empty
        }%
    }%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
    Tried:
    \[\gls{A}[ij]^T\]
    \[\gls{A}[ij^T]\]
    Desired outcome:
    \[A^T_{ij}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially have this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\glsarg}{ij^T}
\[A_{\glsarg}\]
\end{document}
```

which puts `ij^T` as the subscript (that is, `A_{ij^T}`) where `^T` is the superscript of `j`.

The following, which moves the braces, works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\glsarg}{{ij}^T}
\[A_\glsarg\]
\end{document}
```

Applying this to the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\glsnoexpandfields

\newglossaryentry{A}{
    category={arg},
    user1={1},
    name={\(A_{\glsarg}\)},
    text={A_\glsarg},
    description={A}}

\preto\glsentryfmt{%
    \glsifcategory{\glslabel}{arg}% if category set to "arg"
    {%
        \ifdefempty\glsinsert
        {\glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{useri}{\glsarg}}%
        {%
            \let\glsarg\glsinsert
            \let\glsinsert\empty
        }%
    }%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
Compare
\[\gls{A}[{ij}^T]\]
With:
\[A^T_{ij}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Compare A<sup>T</sup><sub>ij</sub> With: A<sup>T</sup><sub>ij</sub>]

Note that with this method you must remember to always apply the grouping in the optional argument if there's more than one subscript. For example:

```
\[\gls{A}[{ij}]\]
```