# How to correspond a symbol in the text to a non-identical symbol in list of symbols?

Tags: glossaries

I have a particular generic function in my document whose signature is `$\mathscr{T}_{i}(\cdot)$`. This function is used with different arguments in the text, e.g., `$\mathscr{T}_{i}(\Lambda_j)$`, `$\mathscr{T}_{i}(\Lambda_j)$`, etc. Using the `glassories` package and `\gls` command, every symbol appearing in the list of symbols is exactly identical to a symbol in the text. However, what I need is the substitution of the function-with-argument with the generic signature of the function in the list of symbols. Here is an `MWE`:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{gloss-symb}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=def,style=mylong,title={List of Symbols}]
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use]

\input{myChap}

\end{document}
```

`myChap.tex`:

```
Here is the function \gls{myFunction}

Here is the function $\mathsf{T}_{i}(\Lambda_j)$
```

`gloss-symb`:

```
\newglossaryentry{myFunction}{name={\ensuremath{\mathsf{T}_{i}(\Omega_j)}},description={The intended function}}
```

The output would be:

[image]

How can I end up with this?:

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier if the document were self-contained.

Comment: @egreg; Can you please clarify what you mean by "self-contained"?

Comment: There's no point in using `\input{...}` and `\loadglsentries` for an example.

Comment: @egreg: I see... Since this document is a thesis including many chapters, `\input`s (and the other imported files) are fairly necessary.

Comment: Related: [Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316777)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

%%% this can go in the gloss-symb file
\protected\def\myFunctionArg{{\cdot}}
\newglossaryentry{myFunction}{
  name={\ensuremath{\mathsf{T}_{i}(\myFunctionArg})},
  description={The intended function},
}
%%% (gloss-symb end)

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vargls}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \@namedef{#1Arg}{#2}%
  \gls{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=def,style=mylong,title={List of Symbols}]

\clearpage

% page 2
Here is the function \vargls{myFunction}{\Omega_j}

\clearpage

% page 3
Here is the function $\vargls{myFunction}{\Lambda_j}$

\end{document}
```

The variable part is stored in `\myFunctionArg` (taking the label as model and adding `Arg`). With `\vargls` we can set the auxiliary macro to whatever we want. Doing it in a group ensures that the initial definition (which needs to be `\protected`) is used for the glossary.

### Page 1 (the list of symbols)

[image]

### Page 2 (the first callout)

[image]

### Page 3 (the second callout)

[image]

Comment: To-the-point and seamlessly perfect, as always. Thanks.