# How to efficiently combine glossaries with custom commands for symbols

Tags: macros, glossaries

For math symbols or operators I open create a custom command such as

```
\newcommand{\prob}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}%
    {%
        p( #1 )
    }{%
        p( #1 \mid #2 )%
    }%
}%
```

to capture the cases where I want to type a conditional or a un-conditional probability with one command, and to be able to change the notation easily if I find out that it is suboptimal.

Now, I also want to create a list of symbols and index using `glossaries` where I would use e.g.

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Probability density functon}]{prob}{\ensuremath{\prob{\cdot}}}
```

To get the glossary and index right, I would be obliged to use e.g. `\gls{prob}` (instead of `\prob`) also e.g. in an `align` environment and $$ math, correct?
But in this case, I cannot make use of the function `\prob` that I defined beforehand.

Now the question: Is there an efficient way to deal with this? I.e. to define (complex) functions that capture multiple possible use cases and make use of the glossary?

Naively speaking, it would be perfect to 'overload' the `\gls` with the options declared for `\prob`, is that possible?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316777).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks so much for the link and the great answer in the linked question!