# glossaries: one entry for every symbol without derivatives

Tags: glossaries

I have created a symbol-list with the `glossaries` package and so far everything worked great. Now, I have to write an equation which includes the derivative of one entry. The derivative is shown by a dot over the symbol. I would like to just do something like: `\dot{\gls{...}}` but this obviously doesn't account for the indices and prints the dot over the middle.

I can just include the derivative in the glossary, but this has some disadvantages:

- If only the derivative is referenced, the glossary will not include the normal symbol.
- If I have multiple derivatives the glossary gets crowded.
- The derivatives have often no "real" meaning, like `a=\dot{v}=\ddot{x}`

Unfortunately, I can't just use the `\prime` operator to show the derivatives, because this is already used to show a transformation.

How can I archive a glossary like that?

Here is one of my entries, maybe it helps:

```
\newglossaryentry{form:komplstatorwiderstand}{
    name=\ensuremath{\uline{Z}_\mathrm{S}},
    description={Statorwiderstand},
    sort=ZS, 
    type=symbolslist
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something like [Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extra fields in the glossaries package: `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, and so on. You call them by using `\glsuseri`, `\glsuserii`, `\glsuseriii` and so on (using roman numerals).

example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{ex}{
    name=\ensuremath{X_\mathrm{S}},
    description={Statorwiderstand},
    sort=ZS, 
    user1 =\ensuremath{\dot{X}_\mathrm{S}}
}

\begin{document}
   Testing the normal \gls{ex} and now with dot \glsuseri{ex}
\end{document}
```