# Nested optional \gls argument exceeds "semantic nest size" capacity

Tags: xetex, glossaries, compilation-error, glossaries-extra

In a math-oriented document, I'm using `glossaries` to link most in-text mathematical symbols to their meaning in the glossary at the front of the document.  Using different subscripts/superscripts doesn't really change their meaning, and so I re-use that entry (and also to prevent the glossary list from growing to unwieldy lengths). Different symbols have different default subscripts, so I use the `user1` field to store the default, and used a slightly modified solution of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229879/221009.

When I nest a `\gls` call inside the optional argument of another `\gls` call, I get the following compile error with `xelatex`:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].
<recently read> {

l.37 $\gls{A}$ and $\gls{A}[x, \gls{B}]
                                       $;
```

This compile error is generated from this MWE

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\glsnoexpandfields{}
\glspatchtabularx{}
\makeglossaries{}

\newcommand*{\glsarg}{} % default glossary argument
\defglsentryfmt{%
  \let\orgglsarg\glsarg%
  \ifdefempty\glsinsert%
  {\glsfieldfetch{\glslabel}{useri}{\glsarg}}%
  {%
    \let\glsarg\glsinsert%
    \let\glsinsert\relax%
  }%
  \glsgenentryfmt%
  \let\glsarg\orgglsarg%
}

\newglossaryentry{A}{description={Some mathematical symbol}, name={\ensuremath{A_{i}}}, text={\ensuremath{A_{\glsarg}}}, user1={i}}
\newglossaryentry{B}{description={Another mathematical symbol}, name={\ensuremath{B_{i}}}, text={\ensuremath{B_{\glsarg}}}, user1={i}}

\begin{document}
\printglossary

\section{My text}
$\gls{A}$ and $\gls{A}[x, \gls{B}]$;
\end{document}
```

Full `mwe.log` file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.7.14)  14 AUG 2021 13:51
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mwe
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2020/01/14 v7.00d Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen135
\Hy@linkcounter=\count171
\Hy@pagecounter=\count172

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count173
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4547.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4552.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4555.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4562.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4567.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4800.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count174

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5159.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen136

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count175
\Field@Width=\dimen137
\Fld@charsize=\dimen138
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6430.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6435.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6438.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6445.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6450.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6455.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6460.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6500.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6504.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
)
\Hy@abspage=\count176
\c@Item=\count177
\c@Hfootnote=\count178
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
File: hxetex.def 2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref driver for XeTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)
\pdfm@box=\box45
\c@Hy@AnnotLevel=\count179
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count180
\Fld@listcount=\count181
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count182

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty
Package: atveryend 2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip49
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra.sty
Package: glossaries-extra 2020/02/13 v1.42 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16
)
\XKV@depth=\count183
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count184
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
\@glsmfirst=\toks17
\@glsmrest=\toks18
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\ex@=\dimen139
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count185
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count186
\leftroot@=\count187
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count188
\DOTSCASE@=\count189
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box46
\strutbox@=\box47
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count190
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count191
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count192
\dspbrk@lvl=\count193
\tag@help=\toks20
\row@=\count194
\column@=\count195
\maxfields@=\count196
\andhelp@=\toks21
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks22
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks23
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count197
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count198
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count199
\FP@xia=\count266
\FP@xib=\count267
\FP@xfa=\count268
\FP@xfb=\count269
\FP@rega=\count270
\FP@regb=\count271
\FP@regs=\count272
\FP@times=\count273
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count274
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks24
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count275
\dtl@tmplength=\skip53
\dtl@sortresult=\count276
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count277
\@dtl@datatype=\count278
\dtl@codeA=\count279
\dtl@codeB=\count280
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count281
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-
307.sty
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
)
\gls@level=\count282
\@gls@tmpb=\toks25
\gls@tmplen=\skip54
\glskeylisttok=\toks26
\glslabeltok=\toks27
\glsshorttok=\toks28
\glslongtok=\toks29

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.st
y
Package: glossary-hypernav 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip55
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip56
\LTright=\skip57
\LTpre=\skip58
\LTpost=\skip59
\LTchunksize=\count283
\LTcapwidth=\dimen148
\LT@head=\box48
\LT@firsthead=\box49
\LT@foot=\box50
\LT@lastfoot=\box51
\LT@cols=\count284
\LT@rows=\count285
\c@LT@tables=\count286
\c@LT@chunks=\count287
\LT@p@ftn=\toks30
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip60
\glspagelistwidth=\skip61
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count288
\ST@wd=\dimen149
\ST@rightskip=\skip62
\ST@leftskip=\skip63
\ST@parfillskip=\skip64
\ST@pageleft=\dimen150
\ST@headht=\dimen151
\ST@tailht=\dimen152
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen153
\ST@pboxht=\dimen154
\ST@lineht=\dimen155
\ST@prevht=\dimen156
\ST@toadd=\dimen157
\ST@dimen=\dimen158
\ST@pbox=\box52
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip65
))
\glsxtrresourcecount=\count289
\@glsxtrnewgls@inner=\count290
\glsshortpltok=\toks31
\glslongpltok=\toks32
)
\glswrite=\write3
\glo@main@file=\write4
\openout4 = `mwe.glo'.

Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file mwe.glo on input line 8.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count291
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count292
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count293
)
(./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 2
6.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box54
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 26.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count294
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 26.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 26.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 26.

(./mwe.out) (./mwe.out)
\@outlinefile=\write5
\openout5 = `mwe.out'.



Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

No file mwe.gls.

Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary `main' is missing on input line 28.


Overfull \hbox (30.99pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--28
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Add \TU/lmtt/m/n/10 automake \TU/lmr/m/n/10 to your package op
tion list when you load \TU/lmtt/m/n/10 glossaries-extra.sty\TU/lmr/m/n/10 .
 []

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/se-ascii-print.def
File: se-ascii-print.def 2019/11/29 v1.12 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters

)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].
<recently read> {
                 
l.30 $\gls{A}$ and $\gls{A}[x, \gls{B}]
                                       $;
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14056 strings out of 479819
 218295 string characters out of 5895846
 668191 words of memory out of 5000000
 31001 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 533192 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 1177i,500n,2343p,998b,20874s stack positions out of 30000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

What is happening (I *think* some recursion is going wrong?), and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't trace where it is looping but a simple workaround is to pre-evaluate the nested content,

```
\newbox\zz
\sbox\zz{\gls{B}}
$\gls{A}$ and $\gls{A}[x, \usebox{\zz}]$;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works as a nice quick fix!